# Keeping irish citizenship through Naturalisation after living abroad

Tags: citizenship, ireland, naturalization

I have seen online that if I live abroad and in order to maintain irish citizenship through Naturalisation I need annually inform the irish immigration of my intention to keep the citizenship. Now is january 2022 but I'm out of Ireland since December 2020.

Do I have to inform them from now on or do I have to inform them after 7 years that I'm abroad but I wish to retain the citizenship?

The citizensinformation.ie mentioned one of the reasons why irish citizenship might be revoked:
"You were ordinarily resident outside Ireland (other than in public service) for a continuous period of 7 years and, without a reasonable excuse, did not register your name and a declaration of your intention to retain Irish citizenship with an Irish diplomatic mission or consular office or with the Minister for Justice every year (by completing Form 5)"

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text; just copy-paste the text itself using a quoteblock (put a "> " before each paragraph of the quote). Otherwise accessibility is reduced for some users, and searchability of the question is affected.

Comment: And what did the consulate say when you asked them?

Comment: I didn't talk with consulate yet. I have sent an email to irish immigration enquiry website. Waiting for reply now.

Comment: Since this is a request for actual advice, would Expatriates be a better fit?

Comment: Where can I get in contact with expatriates